# Can we clean up tags relating to air conditioning?

Tags: discussion, tags

All of the following tags exist, with potentially overlapping topics:

- [air-conditioning](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning), with 991 questions
- [air-conditioner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioner), with 9 questions
- [air](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air), with 45 questions
- [hvac](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hvac), with 2654 questions

Some potentially related tags include [air-leaks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-leaks), [forced-air](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forced-air), [air-sealing](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-sealing), and [central-air](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-air). There's also these tags about air filtration that seem to overlap:

- [air-filter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-filter), with 82 questions
- [air-fil](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-fil), with 1 question
- [air-quality](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-quality), with 100 questions
- [filter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter), with 123 questions (about a wide variety of types of filters)

Some of these should definitely be removed or made synonyms, especially [air-conditioner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioner) and [air-fil](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-fil).

Comment: Also, I stumbled across [tag:flushvlave] while searching for these, which is misspelled and only on a single question.

Comment: There's a policy to clean single use tags after 6 months. Or you can speed it up by submitting an edit to the question to delete the tag. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418

Comment: @BMitch Thanks for the info! I might do that later with [tag:air-fil]. If any of these are going to be synonymized, they'll most likely need a mod since IIRC the non-mod way to do it is pretty difficult.

Comment: We create aliases based on requests here in meta fairly often. What will take me some time is sorting what makes sense as a synonym, merged, or if there's enough different usage that the tags should not be associated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[air-conditioner](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioner) was already a synonym of [air-conditioning](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-conditioning). That's noticeable when you try to go to the air-conditioner tag and it's all the air-conditioning questions. I've gone ahead and merged that one.

I've also edited the one question with [air-fil](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-fil) to use the correct [air-filter](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-filter). I'm guessing that was from using the wrong key to auto-complete, and the system would have eventually deleted it.

If there are other specific entries that need to be defined as a synonym, please raise those as individual suggestions. What I'm looking for is all posts with one tag fitting within a better tag, and no additional value from the original tag.

You can see all the tag synonyms at: https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms